# What is the subject in the sentence below?

Tags: meaning

> Amy Williams said."Just because you're sick doesn't mean you can't do things".

What does this sentence mean? I mean I couldn't understand what the subject is in this sentence. Would it be the same if it is said ;

> Amy Williams said." **IT** doesn't mean you can't do things Just because you're sick''

Comment: The first period should be a comma. The entire sentence is "Amy said X" so *Amy* is the subject. The subject of the quote is the clause "Just because you're sick"; The meaning is the same in your rephrase. The subject is *it*.

Comment: @user105719 Brilliant - please copy and paste it into Answer

Answer (score 1):

> Just because you're sick doesn't mean you can't do things

The reporting clause "Amy Williams said" put aside, the construction "just because X doesn't mean Y" is very common and in a sentence, its first part--just because X--is a clause acting as the subject.

Answer (score 1):

*Amy Williams said, 'Just because you're sick doesn't mean you can't do things'.*

"Amy Williams" is the subject.

Note that the reported speech "Just because ..... " is complement of "said" and has the form of a clause, but the construction involves the embedding of a text, not of a clause as such.

Answer (score 0):

Amy Williams is the subject of the sentence since the sentence is about what she said or is doing.